# How can I do a screen display module in the news?

Tags: module-display

How can I when I click on a menu
Only one module can display

I do not want to set me on my
Because Joomla saves me when I'm
Selection error Catagoris

I just want when I click on the menu
Dedicated show news display module

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying. Can you please make it a little clearer?

Comment: How can I when I click on a menu
Only one module can display

I do not want to set me on my
Because Joomla saves me when I'm
Selection error Catagoris

I just want when I click on the menu
Dedicated show news display module

Comment: If you are referring to assigning a module to 1 page only then this can be done in the module options

Comment: http://koomehdairy.com/index.php/s5-flex-menu-1360/2014-06-17-07-15-43

Comment: I would remove the right
When creating a menu page menu should be considered?
What should I do to just left the module
When clicking on a menu is displayed?

Comment: There is definitely a language barrier issue here. I really don't understand what you mean. Maybe someone else might.

Comment: Yes
I have a problem with English.
I do not understand much English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla always displays a component in the main position, and associated modules with a menu item.

There are several tricks to "hide" the component, and focus visitors attention on a module.

- Display a static article, with no information (a dot), and hide the main position with CSS Styling
- Display a content category, with no articles
- RocketTheme templates have a feature to hide the main component (featured articles). So, you create an alternative template layout with no component.